# How do I prevent hitting the recursion limit in roblox?

Tags: roblox, luau

So I'm making an obfuscator that basically generates a bunch of variables with the byte value of a char.
In the end I have a loadstring that basically combines all the strings into one string.

Now, that works fine with small scripts, but its really when you get big scripts.
It hits the recursion limit.

Here's the code for the obfuscator rn

```
scr = [[
loadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python1111111111111/mosshub/main/main.lua"))()
print("loaded")
]]
local random = Random.new()
local letters = {'i','I','l','_','shus', 'a'}

function getRandomLetter()
    return letters[random:NextInteger(1,#letters)]
end

function getRandomString(length, includeCapitals)
    local length = length or 10
    local str = ''
    for i=1,length do
        local randomLetter = getRandomLetter()
        if includeCapitals and random:NextNumber() > .5 then
            randomLetter = string.upper(randomLetter)
        end
        str = str .. randomLetter
    end
    return str
end
crypt = ""
bytes = ""
vars = {}
function c()
for b = 1,scr:len() do
var = getRandomString(250,false)
crypt = crypt..var.."="..""..string.byte(string.sub(scr,b,b))..";"
table.insert(vars, var)
end
crypt = crypt.."loadstring("
for i,v in pairs(vars) do
crypt = crypt.."string.char("..v..").."
end
crypt = crypt.."\"\")()"

end 
c()
print(crypt)
setclipboard(crypt)
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Since there is no recursion in this code, I believe with a long script you might rather run out of memory or CPU time. You are essentially creating a string that is more than 700 times larger than the input.

Comment: Also, your performance bottleneck is the string concatenation. I suggest you look into using table.concat(...) for combining strings. That is much faster in this scenario.